# Проблема с URL сайта в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, сервер, url, pjax

У себя на сайте нужно использовать Pjax. Из документации нашел, что с ним можно работать так: (это view/site/example)

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <a href="/site/log">asd</a>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Для этого я создал в SiteController:

```
public function actionLog()
{
    return "<h1>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>";
}
```

При нажатии на ссылку "asd" ничего не происходит. Должен был появиться заголовок "ААА..."

Comment: вы по этому адресу (по /site/log) пробовали без pjax переходить? страница отображается?

Comment: Нет. Но по /web/index.php?r=site%2Flog переходит

Comment: вот и ответ, у вас не настроен Urlmanager в конфигах, поэтому на данный момент вы должны использовать `<a href="/web/index.php?r=site%2Flog">asd</a>`

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос. Ваше решение не помогло. Не подскажете, как настроить UrlManager?

Comment: так вы слеш потеряли перед `web` в ссылке, поэтому web дублируется

Comment: Окей. Спасибо. Но ссылка ничего не сделала. (должна была вывести заголовок "ААААА...")

Comment: @Дмитрий Используйте 
`<a href="<?= yii\helper\Url::to(['site/log]) ?>">asd</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы включить ЧПУ заходите в папку `config`, открываете файл `web.php` и ищите такие строчки:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
```

Изначально значение стоит `false`. Поменяйте на `true`.